# built in method to merge two sorted lists in ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have two lists of Foo objects. Each Foo object has a timestamp, Foo.timestamp. Both lists are initially sorted by timestamp in descending order.

I want to merge both the lists of Foo objects in a way where the final list is also sorted by timestamp in descending order.

Implementing this isn't hard, but I was wondering whether there are there any built-in Ruby methods that can do this, as I assume the built-in methods will yield the best performance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This will work, but it will not give great performance because it won't take advantage of the lists already being sorted beforehand:

```
list = (list1 + list2).sort_by(&:timestamp)
```

I don't know of any built-in function that does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I took a quick look at the [`Array#sort`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sort) and [`Enumerable#sort`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) implementations and both appear to use [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). Thus, they *might* not be as efficient as you manually using a [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) that selects which of the two potential elements to output to the new list in turn.

However, [a nice article about self-implemented sorting algorithms](http://philcrissman.com/2010/07/18/how-not-to-write-sorting-algorithms-in-ruby) shows that one programmer's efforts to do better than the underlying quicksort failed miserably -- he did not directly approach the problem you have, but his numbers are daunting enough that I'd try the default [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) sorting first, and only if it feels too slow would I return to trying a self-written merge sort.

Answer (score 2):

Smelly imperative process of merging the two...

```
a = [1,3,7,11]
b = [2,4,6,14]

c = merge_sorted_arrays(a,b)

def merge_sorted_arrays(a,b)
  a.reverse!
  b.reverse!
  output = []

  loop do
    break if a.empty? || b.empty?
    output << (a.last < b.last ? a.pop : b.pop)
  end
  return output + a.reverse + b.reverse
end
```

Maybe using .slice! to take the first element would be better than reversing and popping?

====================

*edited after the fourth comment:*

Right... I've had another play, but need to get on with real work or I'll get fired ;-)

On a large array of integers, my original method works faster than using sort_by, but after filling the arrays with 100,000 OpenStruct objects, and sorting on an attribute, the sort_by was 100-times faster.

Here's my benchmarking results:

```
def pop_merge_sorted_arrays(array1,array2)
  array1.reverse!
  array2.reverse!
  output = []

  loop do
    break if array1.empty? || array2.empty?
    output << (array1.last.my_field < array2.last.my_field ? array1.pop : array2.pop)
  end
  return output + array1.reverse + array2.reverse
end

def shift_merge_sorted_arrays(array1,array2)
  output = []
  loop do
    break if array1.empty? || array2.empty?
    output << (array1.first.my_field < array2.first.my_field ? array1.shift : array2.shift)
  end
  return output + array1 + array2
end

def slice_merge_sorted_arrays(array1,array2)
  output = []
  loop do
    break if array1.empty? || array2.empty?
    output << (array1.first.my_field < array2.first.my_field ? array1.slice!(0) : array2.slice!(0))
  end
  return output + array1 + array2
end

a=(1..100000).map{|x|OpenStruct.new(:my_field => rand)}.sort_by(:my_field)
b=(1..100000).map{|x|OpenStruct.new(:my_field => rand)}.sort_by(:my_field)

# method 1
t=Time.now;w=pop_merge_sorted_arrays(a.clone,b.clone);puts Time.now-t
# average of five runs: 185.96seconds

# method 2
t=Time.now;x=shift_merge_sorted_arrays(a.clone,b.clone);puts Time.now-t
# average of five runs: 0.77seconds

# method 3
t=Time.now;y=slice_merge_sorted_arrays(a.clone,b.clone);puts Time.now-t
# average of five runs: 8.46seconds

# method 4
t=Time.now;z=(a.clone + b.clone).sort_by(&:my_field);puts Time.now-t
# average of five runs: 2.13seconds
```

So the upshot seems to be that you can write a method that will shuffle them while maintaining order that will run quite quickly (and there's probably some more efficiencies to squeeze out of the shift_merge method, but for the extra benefit, is it really worth *not* just bunging them together and using sort_by for the ease of it? :-)

I hope this doesn't count as a digression...

Comment: The OP said "Implementing this isn't hard" so I don't think he was asking you to implement it for him.  Also, you should be able to avoid calling `reverse` four times.

Comment: a) yes... I suggested reversing wasn't great (even though once would be on a nil array.. but still, it's stinky). I was mostly using the code as a starting point that might hint towards ways of shuffling the two together, without calls to sort again. b) I had overlooked the "it's not hard..." in the OP. oops - I would have probably not posted had I noticed that, but I do notice that you implemented a not hard solution too ;-)

Comment: FWIW: I've just had a fiddle with some rough benchmarks - using ".sort_by" on two random-number-filled 100,000 element arrays takes around 0.7 seconds here. Using four ".reverse" calls as above, the same action takes around 0.3 seconds. Removing the reverses, and replacing .pop with .slice!(0) takes over 7 seconds. In real life - sort_by or sort would probably be simple enough to keep it to one line and not worry about it too much :-)

Comment: Interesting.  So `pop` is faster than `slice!(0)`.  What about `shift`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `extend()` method to add `list2` at the end of `list1`:

```
list1 = ["a", "b" , "c"]
list2 = [1, 2, 3]

list1.extend(list2)
print(list1)
```